# Why do know_hosts includes separate entries for IPv4 and hostname?

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to have a better understanding about how SSH works, starting by the `known_hosts` file.

If I SSH to my Raspberry by specifying its IP address for the first time, 1 line line added to `~/.ssh/know_hosts` after I agree to initiate the connection:

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:sPgiqaOhfidX9e1eHeusZWYOiPISsdZGqtkipW11iXQ.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

I can check that 1 line has effectively been added to the `known_hosts` file (considering the file was initially empty):

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts | wc -l
1
```

However, if I try to initiate the connection through the hostname of my RapsberryPi (`raspberrypi.local`), 2 lines are added to the `known_hosts` file: one for the IPv4, one for the hostname.

```
$ ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
...
Warning: Permanently added 'raspberrypi.local,192.168.1.4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.


$ cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts | wc -l
2

$ ssh-keygen -H -F raspberrypi.local
# Host raspberrypi.local found: line 1 
|1|FO/BbuIwNdRi8udGiWxxKb1n/iw=|KX...

$ ssh-keygen -H -F 192.168.1.4
# Host 192.168.1.4 found: line 2
|1|/gHHOjRDGGd3ZyVVIOFKwuf3uKI=|rU...
```

I'd expect to have only one line added, as 192.168.1.4 and rapsberrypi.local are the same host. What's the need for multiple entries based on the host's identifier ?

Comment: It's not obvious that there is an equivalence between a dns name and an IP adress.For exemple you can have an alias dns-name which can change of IP depending of the avaibility of the server behind. You can also have dns round robin which will permute the ip address from a set of IP associated to a uniq dns entry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, it makes sens that a DNS name does not always match the same IP address. I've changed the RaspberryPi IP address to `192.168.1.5` and after initiating a SSH connection to `raspberrypi.local` I've another line added to `known_hosts` corresponding to the new IP. Now I'm wondering how to keep track of hosts I want to be part of this file if for each of them I've one entry corresponding to their IP. Should I only keep track of the DNS name and admit the IP address may change ?